# Decibel calculations, when to use 20 and when 10?

Tags: electrical-engineering

I always thought 20 has to be used for voltage or field strength and 10 for electric power. Now I found this formula which uses power of antennas and they use the factor 20 instead of 10, why?

- [Friis transmission equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friis_transmission_equation#cite_note-AEH-1)

Comment: Just reading your link and it shows the factor of 20 being included when using dB in the other units...

Comment: exactly I don't understand why the factor of 20 thats the whole point of my question, we have power in that formula  (P) so we should use the factor 10 not 20

Comment: If you stick with the original equation then you don't need the factor of 20 and that is needed if you change the units to dB, where the equation changes :_ the last term is no longer squared for example.

Comment: Why didn't you post an answer @SolarMike? When you convert the expression in the parenthesis to dB you end up with 10log(x^2) = 20log(x)

Comment: @idkfa I was hoping that the OP would read and follow his own link, as the formula and developed expression was shown and the reason for it explained...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look carefully:  the equation in linear units has $(\frac{\lambda}{4\pi d})^2$ .
Take the log (as part of the "dB = 10log(x)"), and notice that $log(x^2) = 2log(x)$

Comment: That's a slightly roundabout way of saying to use 20 when a log *power* ratio (which is part of the formal definition) is created from the log ratio of a non-power unit like voltage or current.

Comment: @ChrisStratton true that.   I was just addressing the OP's apparent concern about the "magical" appearance of 20 vs. 10 .